# Vuetify v-data-table - how to make it fill the available height?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vue.js and Vuetify.
I have a page with various sections that contain configurable items for the user.
The layout is a 2x2, so there are two items per row, and 2 rows.

One of the items should contain a table showing alarms.

The problem is the pagination. If I use the "default pagination" then the table starts at 5 rows and the user can select the number of rows in a drop-down.
But I want to use the external pagination of Vuetify. No problem here.

But ... how do I make the table fill up the available height, and compute the pagination based on that?
So that on a large screen ... say ... 12 items are displayed per page and on a smaller screen ... say ... 8 items are displayed?

If there are 24 data entries, then in the first case the external pagination would allow the user to select pages 1 or 2, and in the second case pages 1, 2 and 3.

The default (5 row, 10 rows, 15 rows, ...) ... that's nice but I wonder who would need it. The table should fill the height and calculate the pagination based on number of rows and available height itself ... and it probably/maybe does ... but I cannot figure out, how.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { DeviceAlarm } from '@/api/DashboardApi';
import { getDeviceAlarms } from '@/components/alarms/AlarmsStore';

@Component
export default class Alarms extends Vue {
  deviceAlarms: DeviceAlarm[] = [];
  alarmPagination: any = { sortBy: 'alarmTime', descending: true };

  public mounted(): void {
    this.deviceAlarms = getDeviceAlarms(this.$store);
  };

  get headers() {
    return [
      { text: this.$t('biz.dashboard.alarms.devicename'), align: "left", sortable: true, value: "fridgeDisplayName" },
      { text: this.$t('biz.dashboard.alarms.eventdate'), align: "left", sortable: true, value: "alarmTime" },
      { text: this.$t('biz.dashboard.alarms.status'), align: "left", sortable: false, value: "state" },
      { text: this.$t('biz.dashboard.alarms.information'), align: "left", sortable: false, value: "task" }
    ]
  };

  get pagination() {
    return this.alarmPagination;
  };

  set pagination(newPagination) {
    this.alarmPagination = newPagination;
  };

  get alarms() {
    return this.deviceAlarms;
  };

  get pages() {
    if (this.alarmPagination.rowsPerPage == null || this.alarmPagination.totalItems == null) {
      return 0
    }

    // Test stuff ... how to do that to fill the available space?
    this.alarmPagination.totalItems = this.deviceAlarms.length;
    this.alarmPagination.rowsPerPage = 9;

    let page = Math.ceil(this.alarmPagination.totalItems / this.alarmPagination.rowsPerPage);

    return page;
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-card-title>{{ $t('biz.general.items.alarms') }}</v-card-title>
    <div id="tableDiv">
      <v-data-table :headers='headers' :items='alarms' :pagination.sync='pagination' hide-actions>
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.fridgeDisplayName }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.alarmTime | formatDateTime }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.state }}</td>
          <td>{{ props.item.task }}</td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
      <div class="text-xs-center pt-2">
        <v-pagination circle v-model="pagination.page" :length="pages"></v-pagination>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang = "ts" src="./Alarms.ts"></script>
```

**Answer**

Please see [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53174436/vuetify-layout-problem-for-v-data-table). We made the table fill the height, but it also expanded the pre-set height of the v-card. That's discussed and worked-around in the other thread (where the focus was more on keeping the height and re-doing the pagination on the fly when the size changes).

Comment: Do you have a solution to the problem yet? I think you should create a minimal example for your question so that helpers may have it easier to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, there is actually another question, but the other one answers this one as well. But the final solution we did yesterday afternoon, so I couldn't update this question yet. We realized that this "use the whole page" is something we need to do ourselves. But there were some minor problems (asked in the other question). But ... solved. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53174436/vuetify-layout-problem-for-v-data-table)

Answer (score -1):

For your height issue I suggest using a [v-data-iterator](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterators/) since you can completely customize it for things other than raw data.

As for the table where you want the items per page to be responsive I was thinking you could use computed props in combitation with [vuetify's display breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service-object):

```html
<v-data-table 
  :items="items" 
  :items-per-page="rowsPerPage" 
  :page.sync="page"
  :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
  hide-default-footer />
```

```js
computed: {
  itemsPerPage: function () {
    if(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown) {
      return 2 // Say you want to show 2 items on small screens and smaller
    }
    if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown) {
      return 4
    }
    return 10
  },
  pageCount: function () {      
    return Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.itemsPerPage)
  }
}
```

[Codesandbox for example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-vuetify-jp5mz?file=/src/components/Playground.vue)

If I did not understand you problem correctly, try making a Codesandbox containing the problem to make it easier for us to help you :)